# How to concat multiple excel csv file without inserting files I need

Tags: python, pandas, operating-system

Now I tried to create a code that combine multiple `csv` file in to one `csv` file, as there's no problem about that and that works fine....

here's my code

```
import pandas as pd
import os



mydir = (os.getcwd()).replace('\\', '/') + '/'



# Read all three files into pandas dataframes
f1 = pd.read_csv(r'' + mydir + "BCACACBBABDBBBnir.csv", encoding='latin-1')
f2 = pd.read_csv(r'' + mydir + "BCACACBBABDBBCnir.csv", encoding='latin-1')
f3 = pd.read_csv(r'' + mydir + "BCACACBBABDBBDnir.csv", encoding='latin-1')
f4 = pd.read_csv(r'' + mydir + "BCACACBBABDBDAnir.csv", encoding='latin-1')
f5 = pd.read_csv(r'' + mydir + "BCACACBBABDBDBnir.csv", encoding='latin-1')
........
f107 = pd.read_csv(r'' + mydir + "BCACACBDBDBAABnir.csv", encoding='latin-1')
# Create a list of the files in order you want them appended
all_df_list = [f1, f2, f3, f4, ....., f107]

# Merge all the dataframes in all_df_list
# Pandas will automatically append based on similar column names
appended_df = pd.concat(all_df_list)

# Write the appended dataframe to an excel file
# Add index=False parameter to not include row numbers
appended_df.to_csv("AllBefore.csv", index=False)
```

So Now I need instead to insert all `csv` file I want to combine, as I have hundreds of `csv` files, I just want to create a `for loop` that reads all excel `csv` files in a certain `directory` or `file` and then combine them to one `csv` file.

So, Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

guess this will work

```
basepath = <basepath>
files = list(filter(lambda x: '.csv' in x, os.listdir(basepath)))
alldf = pd.DataFrame()
for f in files:
    df= pd.read_csv(f"{basepath}/{f}",encoding='latin-1')
    alldf = pd.concat([alldf,df])

alldf.to_csv("final.csv")
```

Comment: could you give me an example for base path, I found error like this `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`

when using this path `basepath = "C:\Users\blablabla\PycharmProjects\MyExcelCombine"`

Comment: dear use your encoding label in read csv, encoding='latin-1,i have updated the answer

Comment: basepath is the file path for your csv file directory

Comment: it gives me the same error when I add this path `basepath = 'C:\Users\blablabla\PycharmProjects\MyExcelCombine\myCSV'`

as I updated this line ` df= pd.read_csv(f"{basepath}/{f}",encoding='latin-1')`

Comment: I just need the right syntax to add the path of my directory which contains the csv file :)...
thanks a lot for your support bro :)

Comment: unicode error means it is not the issue of the logic of basepath,you need to add correct encoding label for the file.some examples are utf-8,shift_jis.. please check the correct encoding type for your files

Comment: work perfect when I add r before the file path thanks

Comment: great ,happy coding =D